# How to execute a query multiple times in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

What is the PostgreSQL equivalent to the TSQL “go” statement?

I have a query to insert a record into a table

*--something like this*

```
Insert into employee values(1,'Mike');
GO n;
```

I want this query to be executed n number of times.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try using loop:

```
do
$$
declare 
  i record;
begin
  for i in 1..3 loop
    Insert into employee values(1,'Mike');
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

Answer (score 25):

This is possible without reverting to PL/pgSQL:

```
Insert into employee (id, name)
select 1,'Mike'
from generate_series(1,3);
```

Or if you want different IDs for each row:

```
Insert into employee (id, name)
select id,'Mike'
from generate_series(1,3) as t(id);
```

Comment: +1 it is also faster by about 30% here than the accepted answer inserting a million rows in a local table with random data

Answer (score 1):

https://xzilla.net//blog/2020/Nov/Do-This-10-Times-And-Stop-dot-dot-dot-In-Postgres.html

```
select $$Insert into emp  values(1,'Mike') $$ from generate_series(1,10) \gexec
```

only applicable to psql https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html